# Why would sumproduct (used to return a whole number count) return a fraction?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

UPDATE: So I think the problem is with the unique id 2 values - it's returning ".75" because 3/4s of those values with the "1b" id have a value >0. I've tried integrating roundup into the sumproduct formula but it is not working.. `=SUMPRODUCT((BI200:BI210<>"")/COUNTIF(BI200:BI210,BI200:BI210&"")*(ROUNDUP(($BJ$‌​200:$BJ$210>0),0)))`

I made a formula to identify unique IDs with attributes greater than 0. It seemingly works everywhere on rows 3-1000, except for 200-205. I have no idea why this is the case, and would welcome any insights.

The formula (pictured below) is:
`={SUMPRODUCT((BI200:BI210<>"")/COUNTIF(BI200:BI210,BI200:BI210&"")*(BJ200:BJ210>0))}`

An easier to read version is:
`={SUMPRODUCT((DuplicateIDRange<>"")/COUNTIF(DuplicateIDRange,DuplicateIDRange&"")*(ValueRange>0))}`

The correct answer should be "4" but the formula is returning "3.75". Any ideas?

[image: Current Formula]

Comment: It seems you have answered your question, in the subject of the question, yourself.  Do you have another question?

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not suit your needs

in your column for unique IDs I used the following formula to flag unique ids.  I am not counting like you are, simply flagging the first ID as being unique

```
=--(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=1)
```

Copy that down column C

replace your formula that is resulting in 3.75 with the following

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C1:C11=1)*--(B1:B11>0))
```

Comment: Why are you using the double unary in your `SUMPRODUCT` function?

Comment: what is a double unary?

Comment: The two consecutive negative signs.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(C30:C40=1*B30:B40>0)` gives an answer of 0 but `=SUMPRODUCT(--(C30:C40=1)*--(B30:B40>0))` gives an answer of 4 when I did my testing

Comment: The double unary's are not necessary.  Use `=SUMPRODUCT((C1:C11=1)*(B1:B11>0))`.  Your first example, giving the result of zero, did not have the parentheses around the equality formulas.  Hence, zero would be expected given the precedence that Excel uses to evaluate that formula.  By surrounding with parentheses, it forces Excel to first evaluate each `(...)` and then multiply them, obviating any need for the double unary.